# take a list of numbers from the command line and print the largest number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to write a program that, when given numbers from the command line, manages to read and print the highest number.

```
import sys
numbers = sys.argv[1]
def map(f,items):
   result = [] 
   for i in range(0,len(items),1): 
   result = result + [f(items[i])
   return result
```

im trying to find the easiest way to go about doing this! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

```
import sys
print(max(float(x) for x in sys.argv[1:]))
```

Alternatively, you can use `print(max(sys.argv[1:], key=float))` (thanks to the nice addition by frostnational).

Demo:

```
>> python a.py 12 6 3.14 11
12.0
```

Explanation: If we add `print(sys.argv)` to the script, the output for the above example will be

```
['a.py', '12', '6', '3.14', '11']
12.0
```

The solution is slicing off the first element of `sys.argv`, converting the other strings to floats in a generator expression, and then finding the maximum.

Comment: or `max(sys.argv[1:], key=float)`

Comment: would be helpful if u explain .why `float` and `sys.argv[1:]`

Comment: wow that just made it....so much easier haha. last thing, is write a pgoram that inputs a list of numbers from a file and prints their sum. assume the file "x" contains the numbers:                 4     14                5

Comment: For the sum, change `max` to `sum`

Comment: @timgeb why float and not int

Comment: @iJay because the OP did not specify which type of number.

Comment: Ahh...and `float` would work with both integers and floats but `int` won't ....thnks :)

Comment: write a program that inputs a list of numbers from a file and prints their sum. The file name comes in as a command-line argument
Assuming the ﬁle "orange" contains the numbers:
6 26 10 8
your program should behave as follows:
python3 a4.py orange    50

for my code to do that I will need to implement a scanner correct? however, when I run the updated code with the scanner, it returns a "cannot convert string to float: orange"
sorry if this is a dumb question, but Im taking my first programming class and im trying to get ahead.

Comment: @user3754670 for a different question please open a new question

Comment: It would only let me post once per 90 minutes, sorry about that!

Answer (score 1):

@timgeb answer is very good but i would also check [argparse](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) if you are using the command line interface it can give you some very good option for your current and future code, by using `argparse` you can save a lot of programming time and get a full help and usage messages.

I'll take the example form the docs since it's relevant for your question, this code will print either max or sum.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('integers', metavar='N', type=int, nargs='+',
                   help='an integer for the accumulator')
parser.add_argument('--sum', dest='accumulate', action='store_const',
                   const=sum, default=max,
                   help='sum the integers (default: find the max)')

args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.accumulate(args.integers))
```

**For max:** just call the code with a list of numbers.

**For sum**: or any other option you would like to add you can use an argument, in this case `--sum`

Comment: If the task becomes more complicated than the given example I would definitely recommend using argparse.